# Difference between Torsion and Curvature for a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Consider a curve in 3D space ,it is given by

$r(t)$=$f(t)\hat{i}$+$g(t)\hat{j}$+$h(t)\hat{k}$

[[image: The 3D curve <span class=]$r(t)$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhlae.jpg)

Now what Information does

A)$Curvature$ of this curve give us,

B)$Torsion$ of this curve give us.

I can't seem to understand the difference between these 2 quantities .

Comment: At a very naive level, the torsion measures how much the curve fails to be planar. The curvature measures how much it deviates, "in a planar way" to be a straight line.

Examples: a plane circumference has constant curvature and no torsion. 

An helix has constant torsion and curvature.

Comment: Could you elaborate and explain with respect to this curve ?

Comment: @topolosaurus "At a very naive level, the torsion measures how much the curve fails to be planar" What do you mean by a planar curve?